# Form filter not updating

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two forms PROJECT_VIEW and PROJECT_COMPANY_VIEW. The relationship between these forms is PROJECT_VIEW has a list box populated with companies. Double clicking one of these companies (see code below) will direct you to PROJECT_COMPANY_VIEW.

The issue I am having is: the companyFilter is not being updated on PROJECT_COMPANY_VIEW. As you can see, I am passing it through DoCmd.OpenForm. All of the values that appear in MsgBox are correct, including the COMPANY_ID filter. One thing to note, there are values of a company appearing in PROJECT_COMPANY_VIEW, just not the company I need.

I have tried Clearing All Filters, updating PROJECT_COMPANY_VIEW's record source, deleting the filter in PROJECT_COMPANY_VIEW then closing the form and navigating to it again.

```
Private Sub ProjectTenderList_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim tenderID As Integer
    Dim companyID As Integer
    Dim companyFilter As String
    tenderID = ProjectTenderList.Column(0)
    MsgBox tenderID
    companyID = ProjectTenderList.Column(1)
    MsgBox companyID
    companyFilter = "COMPANY_ID = " & companyID
    MsgBox companyFilter
    DoCmd.OpenForm "PROJECT_COMPANY_VIEW", , companyFilter, , , , tenderID
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is this combobox UNBOUND?

Comment: The `Filter` argument is supposed to be name of a _saved filter_.

Answer (score 1):

Filter criteria is in the wrong argument, needs to be the WHERE CONDITION. Move it over one comma position.

`DoCmd.OpenForm "PROJECT_COMPANY_VIEW", , , companyFilter, , , tenderID`